# How to fix View Pager FragmentManager is already executing transactions

Tags: java, android

The application has a `BottomNavigationView` that controls `ViewPager2`. The application works, but sometimes when moving between interfaces, this error appears:FragmentManager is already executing transactions
I heard about the `getChildFragmentManager()` function, but I did not find it. Can you help me, and also if anyone has any comments about improving the code, thank u

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  List<Fragment> fragmentList=new ArrayList<>();
        tableTime=new ATableTime();
        journal=new BJournal();
        library=new LibraryFragment();
        moreList=new ListFragment();

        fragmentList.add(tableTime);
        fragmentList.add(journal);
        fragmentList.add(library);
        fragmentList.add(moreList);

        viewPager.setUserInputEnabled(false);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getLifecycle(),fragmentList);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);



    }
    void action(){
        bNavView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            if(item.getItemId()==R.id.tableTime ){
               viewPager.setCurrentItem(0,false);
            }
            else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.journal ){
               viewPager.setCurrentItem(1,false);

            } else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.library) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2,false);
            }
            else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.more) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(3,false);
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    private static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
        List<Fragment> arrayList ;
        public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle, List<Fragment> arrayList ) {
            super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
            this.arrayList=arrayList;
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            return arrayList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

    }
}
```

```
**Error**

   

    
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.aziztech.booknote, PID: 4101
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1931)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1967)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:305)
                                                                                                        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer.updateFragmentMaxLifecycle(FragmentStateAdapter.java:726)
                                                                                                        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer$3.onStateChanged(FragmentStateAdapter.java:657)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:271)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:313)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:151)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3026)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:589)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:300)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1971)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:305)
                                                                                                        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.placeFragmentInViewHolder(FragmentStateAdapter.java:341)
                                                                                                        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:276)
                                                                                                        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:67)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchChildAttached(RecyclerView.java:7556)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:860)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:8601)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8559)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8547)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1641)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:640)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24421)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
                                                                                                        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:527)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24421)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1891)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1729)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1638)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24421)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24421)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1891)
2024-01-03 17:04:27.531  4101-4101  AndroidRuntime          com.aziztech.booknote                E      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1729)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1638)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24421)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24421)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1891)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1729)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1638)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24421)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:789)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24421)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3583)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2465)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9305)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1339)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1348)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:952)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:882)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1322)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
2024-01-03 17:04:27.742  4101-4101  Process                 com.aziztech.booknote                I  Sending signal. PID: 4101 SIG: 9
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (4101) for package com.aziztech.booknote ----------------------------
```

Comment: Can you please include the entire stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @ianhanniballake  The code has been modified